# mongo shell: script print messages now shown

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Here my script:

```js
use espaidoc;

// List current indices of the "Audit" collection
print("Current indices of the 'Audit' collection:");
db.Audit.getIndexes().forEach(index => printjson(index));

// Remove all indices for the "Audit" collection
db.Audit.dropIndexes();

print("All indices dropped for the 'Audit' collection.");

// List updated indices of the "Audit" collection
print("Updated indices of the 'Audit' collection:");
db.Audit.getIndexes().forEach(index => printjson(index));
```

I'm executing it using this command:

```
mongosh localhost:27117/mydb -u $MONGODB_USER -p $MONGODB_PASS --authenticationDatabase admin --file audit-indices.js
```

I expected to get output messages into screen. However, what I'm getting is:

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6465d36f447b064dd371b21a
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@localhost:27117/espaidoc?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&authSource=admin&appName=mongosh+1.8.0
Using MongoDB:          6.0.5
Using Mongosh:          1.8.0

Loading file: audit-indices.js
```

I'm not getting above `print("..."` messages.

Any ideas?

Comment: For me it works using mongosh version 1.9.0

Comment: Does `--verbose` give any hints?

Comment: No, I've updated to 1.8.2... The problem is that I need to send my script to other team and I need they send me back generated messages. I don't know which version they have installed. Is there anyway to ensure "logging"?